# Python: error with file op operations

Tags: python

I am loop through json and writing to file and passing that to another funtion to upload using a curl command. 
Here is the error message i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\python_ws\test.py", line 33, in <module>
main((sys.argv[1:]))
File "D:\python_ws\test.py", line 30, in main
upload_file_bams(out_file)
File "D:\python_ws\test.py", line 7, in upload_file
file = open(rel_file).read()
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

I tried different ways but seems like i am missing some basics here. any help is appreciated.

Here is the my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2,json,sys,requests,subprocess,os

def upload_file(rel_file):
    url = "https://localhost:8080/artifactory/list/default.generic.local/ct/releases/"
    user = "john.smith"
    file = open(rel_file).read()
    cmd = 'curl --verbose --user %s --upload-file %s  %s' %(user,file,url)
    print 'trying to execute %s' % cmd
    x = subprocess.Popen('cmd', shell=True)
    #subprocess.call('cmd', shell=True)
    retval = x.wait()

def main(argv):
    #environment 
    env = sys.argv[1]
    rel_name=sys.argv[2]
    consul_url=("http://localhost:9090") % (env)
    list_services = "/v1/catalog/services"
    services_url = consul_url+list_services
    list_of_services = urllib2.urlopen(services_url).read()
    each_service = json.loads(list_of_services)
    #to remove keys with blank values
    newdict = dict([(vkey,vdata) for vkey, vdata in each_service.iteritems() if(vdata) ])
    try:
        out_file = open(rel_name,"wb")
        json.dump(newdict,out_file, indent=4)
    finally:
        out_file.close()
    #uploading release json file to BAMS
    upload_file(out_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main((sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: Make sure you reproduce your indentation correctly if you're going to post Python code. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks. I will make sure to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `upload_file()`, you pass it `out_file` which is of type `file` instead of `string` (file name). The function `open()` takes for the first argument the file name that you want to open.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected it. Seems like I am not getting the response back from the CURL command.